# Oracle 12c startup error: ORA-00093: _shared_pool_reserved_min_alloc must be between 4000 and 0

Tags: oracle, initialization

We have a number of databases at our company. Among them an oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.0 to be precise), but we have no (qualified) oracle DBAs. The performance has deteriorated drastically in the last 6 months or so and I now have the task of finding out why. My research suggested that I should up some memory parameters in the initDBN.ora file. Here's what the original looked like:

```
DBN.__data_transfer_cache_size=0
DBN.__db_cache_size=50331648
DBN.__inmemory_ext_roarea=0
DBN.__inmemory_ext_rwarea=0
DBN.__java_pool_size=79691776
DBN.__large_pool_size=8388608
DBN.__oracle_base='/orabin/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
DBN.__pga_aggregate_target=197132288
DBN.__sga_target=734003200
DBN.__shared_io_pool_size=12582912
DBN.__shared_pool_size=536870912
DBN.__streams_pool_size=4194304
*.audit_file_dest='/orabin/app/oracle/admin/tmf/adump'
*.audit_trail='db'
*.compatible='12.2.0'
*.control_files='/orabin/app/oracle/oradata/tmf/control01.ctl','/orabin/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/tmf/control02.ctl'
*.db_16k_cache_size=8388608
*.db_32k_cache_size=8388608
*.db_4k_cache_size=8388608
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_domain='ubs-hainer.com'
*.db_name='tmf'
*.db_recovery_file_dest='/orabin/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/tmf'
*.db_recovery_file_dest_size=4096m
*.diagnostic_dest='/orabin/app/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=TMFXDB)'
*.local_listener='LISTENER_TMF'
*.memory_max_target=0
*.nls_language='GERMAN'
*.nls_territory='GERMANY'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=188m
*.processes=300
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=700m
*.shared_pool_size=536870912
*.streams_pool_size=4194304
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

Please don't blame me for this, because I did not write it. It certainly doesn't look like the sample init.ora and I am not at all certain where the syntax came from. The values I changed were:

1. DBN.__sga_target=1024m
2. *.sga_target=1024m
3. *.memory_max_target=1408m
4. DBN.__pga_aggregate_target=384m and *.pga_aggregate_target=384m

That's the order in which I made the changes. After each change I used sqlplus to firstly recreate the spffile with:

```
create spfile='spfileDBN.ora' from pfile='initDBN.ora';
```

This was followed by an attempt to startup the database with `startup nomount`. In each case I got an error message which lead me to make the next change.

Finally I got the error which is in the title of this post. When I tried to search for information on this, the findings were grim. Mostly the information dealt with other parameters and did not explain what this error actually meant. The only thing that gave any real background was this link from [Burleson Consulting](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_shared_pool_reserved.htm). It didn't really help me solve the problem, so I decided to revert the initDBN.ora file and do some more research. A slow database is generally better than no database.

But Hey! I still get that same error, even after reerting to the original init file. I'm getting desperate now. I have no idea how to fix this. From what I've read to date, setting "underscore variables" in your init file is a "NO NO".

Can anybody provide me with some helpful tips as to how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Don't know about the _shared_pool parameter from the title (as I am no DBA either), but the buffer cache sizes are odd. The database has 48 MB buffer for it's 8K blocks, and 8 MB each for 4K, 16K and 32K block sizes. 8 MB cache, that's tiny! Please check if the latter ones are used at all, f.i. with `select t.block_size, round(sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024) as mb
  from dba_tablespaces t
  join dba_segments s using (tablespace_name)
 group by t.block_size;`

Comment: Regarding "underscore variables": relax, your's are ok. Official, documented parameters start with a letter. There are undocumented parameters which should officially only be used when advised so by Oracle support. An there are double underscore parameters like `DBN.__pga_aggregate_target`, which are minimum values of dynamic parameters, which are only used during startup. In your case, you can delete all of them from your file.

Comment: @wolφi I cannot run that select statement you suggest until I get the database started. A classic catch-22. I'll look more closely at those cache sizes. I didn't notice that they actually make no sense. BTW, with regard to your comment "underscore parameters like DBN.__pga_aggregate_target, which are minimum values of dynamic parameters,  only used during startup," I was under the impression that the init file was only ever used at startup.

Comment: Re cache sizes, yes, true, they are for later. Re __: I believe they are dynamically changed by Oracle dependend on load etc and stored to the spfile. If you shut down and start up the database, Oracle has a good starting point. For now, you can delete them from your init file. Oracle will arrive later dynamically at good values.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know if the apps running on this database need specific block sizes, but if the priority is getting the database open, you can shrink the init.ora down the smallest, simplest set of parameters that gets you moving forward.

```
*.audit_file_dest='/orabin/app/oracle/admin/tmf/adump'
*.audit_trail='db'
*.compatible='12.2.0'
*.control_files='/orabin/app/oracle/oradata/tmf/control01.ctl','/orabin/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/tmf/control02.ctl'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_domain='ubs-hainer.com'
*.db_name='tmf'
*.db_recovery_file_dest='/orabin/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/tmf'
*.db_recovery_file_dest_size=4096m
*.diagnostic_dest='/orabin/app/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=TMFXDB)'
*.local_listener='LISTENER_TMF'
*.nls_language='GERMAN'
*.nls_territory='GERMANY'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=188m
*.processes=300
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=1000m
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

should get you an open database. Notice I have bumped up the sga_target to 1000m which is about the minimum you need to get a database started.  The *true* values for sga_target and pga_aggregate_target really need to be set based on your expected usage, and the server configuration.  But the init.ora above should get your database running.

Comment: Thanks for the init file, but unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I still get the error `ORA-00093: _shared_pool_reserved_min_alloc must be between 4000 and 0` closely followed by `ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters`. I think I will try just setting that parameter to 3000 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this really qualifies as a "solution", but it does fix the initial problem. As mentioned in my reply to Connor McDonald, I set the parameter `_shared_pool_reserved_min_alloc` to 3000 in the `initDBN.ora file`, which I copied from Connor's example (thanks for that). After recreating the spfile and trying to restart the database, I got the following error:

```
ORA-00093: _shared_pool_reserved_min_alloc must be between 4000 and 11953766
```

That got me thinking that the value 0 in the original error was probably a standin value which really means "the maximum allowed". By actually setting the parameter, I have apparently managed to generate an error which is more meaningful.

The value of `_shared_pool_reserved_min_alloc` is now set to 4200, which is a value I recall reading in one of the less helpful posts. (No, that post did **not** say that this is a value that **should** be used, just that it **could** be used.) This time, after re-creating the spfile I was able to start the database.

Before I do any more fiddling with parameters, I will do a bit more research... or maybe a lot more.